# Fstream not opening the file

Tags: c++, file-handling

I'm trying to open a file for reading:

```
cout << file_path << endl;
fstream myfile(file_path.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
if (myfile.is_open())
    cout << "Yahhy!! file Opend successfully" << endl;
else
    cout << "Wohoo!! Wrong path" << endl;
```

The output is:

```
/home/umar/Desktop/DateFile/dha_dataset.gfp

Wohoo!! Wrong path
```

The path is correct - the file exists, but its not opening the file. Is the problem in my code, or elsewhere?

I am working in Ubuntu.

Comment: possibly you don't have permissions to read?

Comment: create a new file just to test.

Comment: @nyarlathotep I have permissions

Comment: @DogDog still not working :(

Comment: @OOkhan please don't assume, check. what does `ls -al /home/umar/Desktop/DateFile` give you? add the output to your question please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax looks correct, which would leave two options:

Either the file doesn't exist, or you don't have read permission.

To check both do the following command from a terminal:

```
ls -l /home/umar/Desktop/DateFile/dha_dataset.gfp
```

Look at the results, they should look something like:

```
ls: cannot access /home/umar/Desktop/DateFile/dha_dataset.gfp: No such file or directory
```

or:

```
-rw-rw-rw xxx yyy 1025 Oct 9 2013 dha_dataset.gfp
```

The first result means that the path is incorrect.

The second result means the path is correct, so look at the permissions.  If you don't have read permission... (one of the `r`s) then you will be unable to open the file.

Comment: i did what u said am confused with the answer.Check this out
umar@umar-Machine:~/Desktop/DateFile$ ls -l /home/umar/Desktop/DateFile/dha_dataset.gfp
ls: cannot access /home/umar/Desktop/DateFile/dha_dataset.gfp: No such file or directory
umar@umar-Machine:~/Desktop/DateFile$ ls
dha_dataset.gfp
umar@umar-Machine:~/Desktop/DateFile$ pwd
/home/umar/Desktop/DateFile
umar@umar-Machine:~/Desktop/DateFile$

Comment: please add that to your question and format it properly! like this it's unreadable. looks like either the file doesn't exist, or there's no permissions ;)